# Strange DateTimePicker Formatting Behavior

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have a small form that includes a `DateTimePicker` control. I've customized it so that it formats its dates to `dd/MM/yy`. However, when the user presses "send", its value is displayed in my `CheckedListBox` as `dd/month/yy`.

For example, if the user sets the date to "19/04/11", it shows up in the `CheckedListBox` as "19-Apr-2011". Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this may be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the format of the Date before passing to the Checkedlistbox by making it as

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy"));
```

Comment: here is the code private void addNewItem()
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(itemName.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value);

Comment: Now, i changed the Code. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CustomFormat` property of your `DateTimePicker` control to "dd/MM/yy"..

The Format property must be set to DateTimePickerFormat.Custom for this property to affect the formatting of the displayed date and time.

However, the `Value` property is not formatted unless the `Checked` property is set to true. If the `Checked` property was set to false only `Text` property value is formatted ..

---

Refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.checked.aspx

Comment: i did it, when the user choose the date it's work fine, but when it's displayed in the listBox , it showed as the defult property